# Modeling dataset using SVM

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, classification, svm

I have job to modeling dataset KDD 99 using Support Vector Machine (SVM).
Here is the code that i try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train,test=train_test_split(model,test_size=0.3)
train_x=train.iloc[:,:-1]
train_y=train.iloc[:,-1]
test_x=test.iloc[:,:-1]
test_y=test.iloc[:,-1]
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier= SVC()
```

When i use this code :

```
classifier.fit(train_x,train_y)
```

and i got errors like this :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-002fa45b4d55> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier.fit(train_x,train_y)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    148                          order='C', accept_sparse='csr',
    149                          accept_large_sparse=False)
--> 150         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    151 
    152         sample_weight = np.asarray([]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in _validate_targets(self, y)
    517     def _validate_targets(self, y):
    518         y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 519         check_classification_targets(y)
    520         cls, y = np.unique(y_, return_inverse=True)
    521         self.class_weight_ = compute_class_weight(self.class_weight, cls, y_)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.pyc in check_classification_targets(y)
    169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 171         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    172 
    173 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Hope anyone can help me to solve this problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: You shouldn't use images to provide error messages. Use text instead

Comment: thank you for suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass categorical class labels for classification using `SVC`. I think you are now passing real numbers as class label `train_y` or `test_y`. Your class labels should be `int` or `string`.